# iOS - Unable to install app, “CFBundleExecutable” is not specified

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Super strange, all of a sudden when I attempt to run my project on my device, I'm being thrown the following error:

```
   Unable to install “App”
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: -1
    Recovery Suggestion: “App” does not contain a valid Info.plist, so it cannot be installed on iPhone (2)
    
    (“CFBundleExecutable” is not specified)
    User Info: {
        DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-03-10 19:55:34 +0000";
        IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    }
```

I've confirmed that info.plist does in fact exist in my project.

**Inside the info.plist, string Executable File is set to:** $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

And in my **Build Settings**, under 'Packaging', Info.plist file is specified as App/info.plist.

No idea why this is happening all of a sudden. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you manually move your `info.plist` to another folder.

---

**The problem is**

In your Build Settings, under `Packaging`, `Info.plist` file is specified as `your project name/info.plist` however your `info.plist` exactly exist in `your project name/.../info.plist`

**Solution**

you can try to modify your new `Info.plist` path in Build Settings.